# Change styles in EB Garamond Math

Tags: math-fonts, ebgaramond

I would like to use the EB Garamond font in a math document. However, several math symbols don't appear as I would like to. The main problem is the letter f in math mode, which doesn't look as I would prefer.

Here is a sample code to show the problem

```
\documentclass[8pt,openany]{book} 
\usepackage[vvarbb,ebgaramond,smallerops]{newtx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}


\begin{document}

Whenever I use math mode, the symbol $f$ is used whether I would prefer something like $\textit{f}$. 

\end{document}
```

I suppose there must be sylistic options one can tune, but have no idea how to do that.

[image: f vs f]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
\documentclass[8pt,openany]{book} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[vvarbb,ebgaramond,smallerops]{newtx}
\DeclareSymbolFont{XYZ}{T1}{\familydefault}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{f}{\mathalpha}{XYZ}{`f}

\begin{document}

$f$ vs. $\textit{f}$. 

\end{document}
```

[image]